# Parents width auto and child with fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have centered and fixed width child in parent element. When horizontal scroll appears, for example on mobile devices, parents width becomes smaller than childs and because there is background-color on parent it looks ugly, how can I fix this?

```css
.parent {
  background: #555;
}

.child {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quas aut reiciendis quaerat, possimus, quidem veniam et sequi ullam labore obcaecati iure alias iusto atque explicabo facere, aperiam nobis quam.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: overflow: hidden; in parent, not sure if that what you want.

Comment: i wonder why parents width != childrens with small viewport, how can i achieve this?

Comment: ok then check @Vahid Boreiri answer fixes it.

Comment: The default width of a div is simply the width of the parent, not the width of the contents. That's just how it is. Altering properties of other divs does not change that.

Comment: yeah just realized that, thanks. min-width: 1000px on parent solves this, but i thought there could be more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Make the `.parent` an `inline-block` with `min-width: 100%` so it grows to fit the browser, but also will not shrink to smaller than its content**

```css
.parent {
  background: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.child {
  width: 1000px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quas aut reiciendis quaerat, possimus, quidem veniam et sequi ullam labore obcaecati iure alias iusto atque explicabo facere, aperiam nobis quam.</div>
</div>
```

---

Three options based on the code you provided:

**Put the width on the `.parent` element instead**

```css
.parent {
  background: #555;
  width: 1000px;
}

.child {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quas aut reiciendis quaerat, possimus, quidem veniam et sequi ullam labore obcaecati iure alias iusto atque explicabo facere, aperiam nobis quam.</div>
</div>
```

**Make the `.parent` an inline-block so it grows based on contents**

```css
.parent {
  background: #555;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  width: 1000px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quas aut reiciendis quaerat, possimus, quidem veniam et sequi ullam labore obcaecati iure alias iusto atque explicabo facere, aperiam nobis quam.</div>
</div>
```

**Make the `.parent` element scrollable**

```css
.parent {
  background: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 1000px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quas aut reiciendis quaerat, possimus, quidem veniam et sequi ullam labore obcaecati iure alias iusto atque explicabo facere, aperiam nobis quam.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i need parents background color to be full width

Comment: @JohnDuzzle I suggest that the most applicable one for you is probably the `inline-block` solution.

Comment: sry i meant full viewport width with no scroll on parent

Comment: @JohnDuzzle The third solution (`overflow: auto`) should do that. The `.parent` will fill the viewport as always and allow you to scroll if your viewport is under 1000px in width.

Comment: yeah but I want entire page to scroll not only parent

Comment: @JohnDuzzle Got it. Why didn't you say so? ;) I've added a fourth solution to the top of my answer.